# R: convert daily data to monthly average

Tags: r, xts

I am able to convert daily H,L,C data to monthly H, L, C data:

```
library(xts)
data(sample_matrix)
samplexts <- as.xts(sample_matrix)
to.monthly(sample xts)
```

But how can I easily obtain the monthly averages from the daily data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 ways of doing this with xts

Simple way: using the `apply.x` functions (where x is the period) . In this case `apply.monthly`:

```
apply.monthly(samplexts, mean)
               Open     High      Low    Close
2007-01-31 50.21140 50.31528 50.12072 50.22791
2007-02-28 50.78427 50.88091 50.69639 50.79533
2007-03-31 49.53185 49.61232 49.40435 49.48246
2007-04-30 49.62687 49.71287 49.53189 49.62978
2007-05-31 48.31942 48.41694 48.18960 48.26699
2007-06-30 47.47717 47.57592 47.38255 47.46899
```

Or the more complicated way using `period.apply` which is used in the call to `apply.monthly` and other apply.x functions. This can give you a more finely tuned control if there is a missing period for the apply.x functions.

```
period.apply(samplexts, INDEX = endpoints(samplexts, on = "months"), FUN = mean)
               Open     High      Low    Close
2007-01-31 50.21140 50.31528 50.12072 50.22791
2007-02-28 50.78427 50.88091 50.69639 50.79533
2007-03-31 49.53185 49.61232 49.40435 49.48246
2007-04-30 49.62687 49.71287 49.53189 49.62978
2007-05-31 48.31942 48.41694 48.18960 48.26699
2007-06-30 47.47717 47.57592 47.38255 47.46899
```

Comment: That's great. Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to do it using dplyr package

```
# create sequence of data
dates = seq(as.Date('2011-01-01'),as.Date('2011-12-31'),by = 1)
data = data.frame(dates, num = rnorm(1:365))

# create month and year column
data$month = lubridate::month(data$dates)
data$year = lubridate::year(data$dates)

# view data
head(data)

# load library
library(dplyr)

# summarize data as needed
data %>% group_by(year,month) %>% summarize(numMean = mean(num)) %>% as.data.frame
```